# strike through a selected row in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, nsattributedstring

I am new to mac app.In my application i have booked history tableview.when the user click on "withdraw" button,I want to strike through the selected row of the tableview.And I am getting tableview content from NSArraycontroller.I don't know how to do it.If any one knows,guide me to do.
This is in mac osx,not in ios.

Answer (score 1):

One way to obtain this would be to use a `NSTextView` inside your table cell and then bind the attribute string to you array controller. Now in the array controller you can change the relative value by adding an attribute of the type `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName`.